# Problems related to using <Link/> react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

When we use the `<Link/>` `react-router-dom`, because the dom is not rerendered, the javascript codes are not executed even if we change the state (in some cases).

If I want to give two examples:

1. If I move between pages through the link tag and want an element to change after displaying the page if a condition is met, this does not happen.
2. When the React project is run on a mobile device that has a small screen, the JavaScript codes are executed only once for the mobile mode menu.

How can JavaScript codes be executed again without loading or rerendering the page when we use the link tag in React to move between pages?

Thanks to those who help!

Comment: Hey, could you provide a minimal reproducible example ?

Comment: For example, if a photo is in mobile mode, its height decreased and vice versa . @shantr

Comment: I'm not really sure about what codes you want to be executed again when moving  between pages. If you have some minimal code to show it would help a lot to better understand your problem !

Comment: Sorry, we can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see, so please edit your post to include a [mcve] so we've context what the code is doing and what you are asking for help with.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this help you.
use the key attribute in main div tag in page components and put the value of the key attribute={window.location.pathname}

Comment: Do you mean this way?<div key={window.location.pathname}>elements</div>

Comment: yes.............